# How to include CDN in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-dialog

I know how to include CDN in HTML file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

But what I am trying to do is:
I want to include CDN like jquery in my javascript file.

May be what I am trying to do is impossible.
Actually, I want to call *BootstrapDialog.Confirm* from my javascript file.
So, I want to include required CDN for BootstrapDialog in js file.
Then I can call *BootstrapDialog.Confirm*.

If my question is not reasonable, forgive me as I am a beginner.

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to load the scripts like your example?

Comment: If it's something you're passing out to clients, make sure you aren't mangling their existing jquery. (no conflict)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can do it in Javascript:

```
var jQueryScript = document.createElement('script');  
jQueryScript.setAttribute('src','https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js');
document.head.appendChild(jQueryScript);
```

Answer (score 3):

Using document.write you can include the cdn

```
 document.write(
      unescape("%3Cscript src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E")
    );
```